# How to create alternative linux boot without starting some services

Tags: linux, boot, grub, services

I would like to create an alternative booting possibility in my GRUB menu that does not start some services (listed by chkconfig) like cups.

I would use this boot during travel where I surely does not need these services and shorter bootup time is preferable. Permanent removal of such services is not an option because I could not miss them during normal daily work.

I use Mandriva 2010 with the latest updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `chkconfig` et alia to configure the services in runlevel 4 as you like, then add an entry to grub that boots in it (probably by adding a `4` to the end of the `kernel` line).

Comment: Thanks it is working, however it does not solve the original problem, the boot is still very slow.